# Как можно подсчитать колличество слайдов в API fotorama.io?

Tags: jquery

Всем привет!
Как можно подсчитать колличество слайдов в API http://fotorama.io?

Например: 1 из 8 слайдов.

Comment: а непосредственно у изобретателя этого сервиса нельзя уточнить?

Comment: `$('.fotorama__thumb').length`

Comment: Спасибо, Артем!